# bootstrap tooltip not considering data-placement parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have added bootstrap tooltip parameters as follows on my element :

```
<input type="text" name="appbundle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="My title" class="form-control">
```

I also have added the following script :

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Well, the tooltip is displaying but it is not respecting the data-placement parameter : it's always at the bottom of the control.

I have seen there was some issues with positioning but all i found was from long ago and I have now bootstrap 3.3.1.

Any clue on how to resolve this ?

Edit:
Here is a sample code with the same librairies I am using. Still not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap-3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap-3.3.1/js/npm.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <p>test</p>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="appbundle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="My title" class="form-control">

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Works fine for me http://www.bootply.com/OVIZSqxtC3

Comment: Please post a complete live example of the problem.

Comment: well, I'm developping locally with symfony and I have many other librairies. I guess one of them is altering default bootstrap behaviour. I'll try to figure out which one and revert...

Comment: I have added a full example for you to look at. I still don't get what's wrong

Comment: @Danko : I still don't get it. Can you point me towards the sole cdn files necessary to achieve the result of your example? I have updated  my libraries without success. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found it!

I was adding bootstrap js before jquery ui and that caused the issue.
The same went for some other libraries.

Place bootstrap js at the end !

Comment: Now realized the order of .js files matters a lot.

Comment: Big life saver thank you. After spending a lot of time updating bootstrap to the newest version, trying different ways of activating, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem came from `overflow` style.

In this example, when I set `overflow: auto` for the `.container1` element, the tooltip message will be shown wrong.

Since I remove it from `.container2`, the problem is fixed.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip().tooltip('show');
});
```

```css
[class^=container] {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}

.container1 {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container1">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="This is a title">Hover me</button>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="This is a title">Hover me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to use it in container1, use `boundary` option. Check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/tooltips/#usage.

Answer (score 1):

Use this order of your jquery and bootstrap js files

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```